# Is there a way to add Tags to elements in PowerPoint via the UI?

Tags: powerpoint

PowerPoint documents can contain custom Tags on Shapes and Slides: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/tagging-presentations-slides-shapes

Is there a way to set these tags via the PowerPoint UI, without the need to write a custom addin?

Answer (score 0):

> > PowerPoint documents can contain custom Tags on Shapes and Slides:

And on the presentation itself.

> > Is there a way to set these tags via the PowerPoint UI, without the need to write a custom addin?

No, afraid not. I suspect that tags were introduced *specifically* as a way for developers to store information in a way that's invisible to users.